# flatpickr: how to remove today circle?

Tags: javascript, flatpickr

I'm using flatpickr javascript plugin to select dates. Now I want to remove circle around today.
How to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With js :

```
instance.config.onOpen.push(function() { $(".flatpickr-day.today").style.borderColor = "transparent" });
instance.config.onMonthChange.push(function() { $(".flatpickr-day.today").style.borderColor = "transparent" });
```

With CSS :

```
.flatpickr-day.today {
    border-color: transparent;
}

.flatpickr-day.today:hover, .flatpickr-day.today:focus {
    background: #e6e6e6;
    border-color: #e6e6e6;
}
```